# How to update day points everyday using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am having this project to update the data everyday and I just want it to update like realtime date everyday without opening the website like trigger or some timer in my database.

For example there like points system for bronze account there would be 1 points everyday how can I do that in php mysql thank you for the help

Comment: You can use cron.

Comment: is this works even if i did not open my browser? something like even if my browser does not online it still update?

Comment: yes, that's what it was made for, to run behind the scenes of the outside web

Comment: should it work without using NPM like putting the script inside my php files? like downloading the script file then adding to my script tag? because i did not use NPM in my project

Comment: That I doubt very much. Cron doesn't interact with people on the outside world.

Comment: hmmmm ill just try these if these updates without using NPM thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ill just find out the answer to my problem ill just use the MYSQL Event to update the points every day and let the date update everyday  .